# Aggregating on the aggregated values in pandas returns wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have such [dataframe](https://yadi.sk/d/reQwA5cq3Tnuyd) - each transaction might appear more than one, and transactions linked to stores. I want to find mean value of transaction. For that I need to sum and then find mean value:

```
#preparind dataset
txt_data = pandas.read_csv("./TestDataSource/txn.csv", sep = ';')
txt_data = txt_data.replace({',': '.'}, regex=True)
txt_data[['SALES']] = txt_data[[ 'SALES']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

[image]

We have `len(txt_data.STORE.unique())` only 30 unique STORE here.

First of all I aggregate on transactions:

```
a1 = txt_data[['STORE', 'SALES', 'TXN']].groupby('TXN').sum()[['STORE', 'SALES']]
a.head()
```

[image]

Everything seems to be okay. But then I aggregate on stores:

```
a2 = a1.groupby('STORE').mean()
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

But...
`list(a2.shape)` - returns [1137, 1] . Thats really confusing. But moreover `len(a1.STORE.unique())` returns 1137

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem you aggregate `STORE` and `SALES` columns by `sum` per `TXN` column:

```
a1 = txt_data[['STORE', 'SALES', 'TXN']].groupby('TXN').sum()[['STORE', 'SALES']]
```

What is same as:

```
a1 = txt_data.groupby('TXN')['STORE', 'SALES'].sum()
```

But if aggregate by column `TXT` and `STORE` all working nice:

```
txt_data = pd.read_csv("txn.csv", sep = ';', decimal=',')

a1 = txt_data.groupby(['TXN', 'STORE'], as_index=False)['SALES'].sum()

print (txt_data.STORE.nunique())
30

print (a1.STORE.nunique())
30
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
a1 = txt_data[['STORE', 'SALES', 'TXN']].groupby('TXN').sum()[['STORE', 'SALES']]
```

your are grouping your dataframe by `TXN`, but tell pandas to sum all other columns, so you get the store-ids summed and "new stores created", e.g.:

```
txt_data[txt_data['TXN']==5541359000]  

               DAY  STORE   ART                    TXN      TIME    SALES
1268877 2015-10-01  1082    15294488        5541359000  09:30:22    60.2
1269093 2015-10-01  1082    80439           5541359000  09:30:29    15.6
1269309 2015-10-01  1082    191452          5541359000  09:30:15    4.0
1269525 2015-10-01  1082    15317962        5541359000  09:30:17    103.0

a1.head()
           STORE    SALES
TXN     
5541359000  4328    182.8

#1082 * 4 = 4328
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is happened when you used this line,

```
a1 = txt_data[['STORE', 'SALES', 'TXN']].groupby('TXN').sum()
```

When I get unique values using txt_data['STORE'].unique() it outputs,

```
array([22691, 20581,  1574,  1602,  1579, 29245, 19009, 21761, 17474,
        1544,  1612,  1534,   958, 17096,  1094,  1596,  1594,  1609,
       24605,   956,   961,  1122, 27220,   974,  1082, 25039,  1530,
         999,  1053,   980])
```

But In the a1 Dataframe,
STORE values are diffrent than txt_data because group_by.sum() summed values in STORE inorder to get unique 'TXN's.
[image]

**See : There is no STORE = 4328 in txt_data['STORE'].unique()**

[image]

1082 * 4 = 4328